# Is there a repository of pre-built JUnit tests for common Java Interfaces?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm teaching a data structures class this semester and we build gobs of JUnit tests given component interfaces.  We then use `setUp` to plug in a specific concrete implementation.  In most cases we are implementing java.util interfaces.  Is there a common set of rigorous JUnit tests for common Java components, or some sort of framework that makes designing the test cases less painful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) provides several matchers that are specific to Maps and Collections.
You can find them in the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial).

(JUnit 4.x contains Hamcrest)

**Sample code:**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DummyTest{

    @Test
    public void someTest(){

        final Collection<Integer> coll = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        assertThat(coll, hasItems(5, 4, 3, 2, 1));
        assertThat(coll, not(hasItems(6)));
        assertThat(coll,
            both(
                is(List.class)
            ).and(
                equalTo(
                    Arrays.asList(
                        0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5
                    )
            )
        ));

    }



}
```

Your main starting point would be these convenience classes:

- [CoreMatchers](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html)
- [JUnitMatchers](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/junit/matchers/JUnitMatchers.html)

Comment: Am I the only one that find that kind of "syntax" awful?

Answer (score 2):

For these purposes [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) may be the easiest way of having "concrete" implementations used by unit tests. One of the best is [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could look at how Apache Harmony and GNU Classpath unit test their respective clean-room  implementations of the `java.util` classes.